# Can't show SQLite data in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a database called `books.sqlpro` in `src/main/assets` with columns `id`, `title`, `author` and `body`.

I'd like to populate a ListView with all the authors in the database in alphabetical order.

I'm not surprised it's not working given I haven't specified my database location, but the only error it gives is `Cannot resolve method 'getReadableDatabase()'`.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.apple.bookshelf;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mainListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

        String Table_Name = "books";
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table_Name;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String[] NameArray = new String[cursor.count()];

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NameArray);

        mainListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.getReadableDatabase()` will, as you have found not work as it is a method of the SQLiteOpenHelper class of which you would need a subclass.

The following is a very crude way of getting your list of authors. Basically it copies the database in the assets file to the standard database location (if it doesn't already exist). Gets a cursor for all rows and then displays them in the ListView.

```
    final String DBNAME = "books.sqlpro";
    final String DBPATH = this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    final String TBNAME = "books";
    final String AUTHOR_COL = "author";
    String outfilename = DBPATH + DBNAME;
    SQLiteDatabase booksdb;

    try {
        booksdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(outfilename,
            null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            InputStream is = this.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            booksdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(outfilename,
                null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
            );
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Cursor csr = booksdb.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    String[] authorlist = new String[csr.getCount()];
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        authorlist[csr.getPosition()] = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(AUTHOR_COL));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        authorlist
    );
    mListView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

From this, the database created in SQLite Manager and copied into the assets folder of the project as **books.sqlpro** :-

[image]

To this, a list view with the authors (note hijacked another project for this, hence the other lists) :-

[image]